# Python histogram in log space with one bin centered at a specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to create a histogram in matplotlib that fulfills a few specific requirements but am having trouble. What it needs to do:

1. Both axes need to be in logspace
2. The bins need to be uniform in size in log space.
3. There need to be exactly five bins per dex (order of magnitude)
4. Three of the bins needs to be centered at/include the values 1, 10, and 100.

I have figured out 1-3, but can't find a way to also accomplish 4.  This is what I'm doing. The actual data is from a pandas data frame. This question has been updated to provide an example.

```
data = np.random.uniform(0.01,300,size=200)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)

plt.figure()
plt.hist(dataframe[0],bins=np.logspace(np.log10(0.1),np.log10(1000),21),edgecolor='k',facecolor='None',align='mid')
plt.gca().set_xscale('log')
plt.gca().set_yscale('log')
```

This would be perfect, except for not fulfilling 4.  Does anyone have suggestions on how to reconcile these requirements? Thank you so much.

### Current Output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to this seems to be generating the right bin boundaries, so if you add an additional bin and shift them all half a bin to the left you get this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.uniform(0.01, 300, size=200)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)

plt.figure()
plt.hist(dataframe[0], bins=10.0 ** np.linspace(-1.1, 3.1, 22),
         edgecolor='k', facecolor='None', align='mid')
plt.gca().set_xscale('log')
plt.gca().set_yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Shifting them by the right amount was what I was struggling with and this does that perfectly.  Thank you!